# Customize Forgot Password Email .Meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

This function below works just fine. But How do I change the sender parameters of the forgot password email.

```
sendForgotpasswordmail() {
    let options = {};
    options.email = this.state.email;
    Accounts.forgotPassword(options, function(error){

        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            alert('Check your mailbox!');
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever I send that I get the sender as `From: "Meteor Accounts" <no-reply@meteor.com>`
 and that is what I want to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change this by adding the following:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.from = function () {
   // Overrides value set in Accounts.emailTemplates.from when resetting passwords
   return "AwesomeSite Password Reset <no-reply@example.com>";
};
```

Further explained in the docs:
http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-emailTemplates

Comment: It works . I put the code in the meteor start_up method and it worked